# How to import youtube account and password from other browsers to cobalt

Tags: youtube, cobalt

We need to change the browser used by youtube from another browser to use cobalt. During the software upgrade, we need to import youtube account and password into cobalt.So，how do we import the data into the cobalt?
   I know that cobalt can support cookies, localstorage, cache. How are youtube accounts and passwords stored? What do we need to do with cobalt?

Answer (score 1):

Cookie and local storage migration mechanism will kick in automatically (see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/storage_manager.cc#286) when you return an upgrade data from SbStorageReadRecord(). For example of upgrade data, see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/upgrade/testdata/full_data_v1.json. For upgrade data schema description, see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/upgrade/schema_v1.proto.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't care about handling YouTube user credentials while porting Cobalt on your platform. Implementing Storage APIs in your Starboard correctly should fix handling the credentials. cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/starboard/storag‌​e.h

Comment: @zhoxi.xiong, sorry, I realized that I mis-read your question. I will get back to this thread soon with a better answer.

Comment: As for migration mechanism, it'll kick in automatically (https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/storage_manager.cc#286) when return an upgrade data from SbStorageReadRecord(). For example of upgrade data, see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/upgrade/testdata/full_data_v1.json. For upgrade data schema description, see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/storage/upgrade/schema_v1.proto. The following reply from cobalt:But what path should we put this json file, what function does cobalt use to read this file?